# Diferencia entre "transformar" y "convertir"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, sinónimos

En el chat [se ha debatido](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48499287#48499287) la corrección gramatical de un texto, en el cual se incluye la siguiente frase:

> [...] la tradición [de hablar como un pirata] se transformó en un día festivo internacional por la Iglesia del Monstruo de Espagueti Volador.

En un principio no vi nada raro en la frase, pero luego me di cuenta de que yo habría usado el verbo *convertir* en vez de *transformar*.

Según el DLE, las acepciones más generales para ambos verbos son:

> **[convertir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Agvhx9z)**
>
> 1. tr. Hacer que alguien o algo se transforme en algo distinto de lo que era.
>
> **[transformar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aJbn4er)**
>
> 1. tr. Hacer cambiar de forma a alguien o algo.

El hecho de que el verbo *transformar* implique un cambio de forma hace me cuestione la idoneidad de su uso para el caso de cosas que no tienen forma: una *tradición* y un *día festivo*. Sin embargo, el verbo *transformar* parece que tiene una segunda acepción más genérica:

> 2. tr. Transmutar algo en otra cosa.

Y *[transmutar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aM4kGZc)* es "mudar o convertir algo en otra cosa", con lo que de nuevo tenemos el verbo *convertir*. Y no solo eso, sino que además si nos fijamos en la definición de *convertir*, esta usa el verbo *transformar*.

Así pues, pregunto: ¿son los verbos *transformar* y *convertir* completamente intercambiables en las mencionadas acepciones? ¿O se prefiere el uso del primero para objetos materiales (con *forma*) y el segundo para cosas inmateriales o como opción más genérica?

Comment: Para mi son sinónimos exactos. ¿Tiene la RAE un diccionario de sinónimos? Bueno, transformar es "cambiar de forma". Convertir requiere decir en que se transformó

Answer (score 2):

¡Hola Charlie!

En Español (castellano), se pueden usar indistintamente. Como bien dices, tienen unas pequeñas diferencias de uso, pero no suelen ser importantes. Te doy algunos ejemplos:

> - El agua se **transformó** en hielo / El agua se **convirtió** en hielo.

Un ejemplo para personas sería:

> - Clark Kent se **convirtió** en Superman / Clark Kent se **transformó** en Superman.

Sólo conozco un ejemplo en el que se suele usar siempre convertir en lugar de transformar y es para explicar una conversión religiosa.

> La tribu se **convirtió** al cristianismo.

En este caso nunca se suele usar transformar. Un hispanohablante te entenderá sin importar si usas convertir o transformar, pero en este caso concreto es más común usar convertir.

Espero haberte ayudado :-).

Answer (score 0):

Para mi aunque suenan parecidos, pero son completamente distintos los significados. CONVERTIR: es cambiar completamente de Estados . El gusano, se convirtio en una Linda Mariposa. Es conversion totalmente diferente.
TRANSFORMARSE: una pieza de oro, la transformaron en un hermoso anillo.  Sigue siendo lo mismo solo tiene una forma diferente.